# Unity3D: How do I move a cube on the surface of a sphere-like complex geometry? (I want the cube to be stuck on the surface of the sphere)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm working on this school project where I have to make a space-game-thing. The whole premise of the game is that you go around the moon in a rover, collecting data from across it. The problem I'm facing is that the code that I'm using (stolen from various stack-overflow and unity-help forums) makes the cube (rover) move around, except it moves around freely. **I want the cube to be stuck on the surface of the moon. **

Note: The moon is **NOT** a simple sphere, it's a complex object with many irregularities. Hence I can't use some like containing the movement of the rover to a fixed radius.

The cube is attracted to the moon gravitationally, and I've even gotten the bottom face of the cube to be oriented towards the center of the moon. It's just that the cube moves around the sphere, not always on the surface as I'd like it to. Also, for some reason the cube likes to come back to the equator of the moon. Please tell me a way in which I can sorta like glue the bottom face of the cube onto the moon's surface. If you guys need any more clarification, think about the movement controls of Sebastian Lague's Geographical Adventures, of course removing the plane's up and down motion and also making the controls suitable for a ground vehicle.

Thanks guys

Code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeController : MonoBehaviour

{
    public Transform centerPoint;  
    public float gravitationalForce = 10f; 
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;

    private Rigidbody rb;


    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.useGravity = false;
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 gravityDirection = (centerPoint.position - transform.position).normalized;
        rb.AddForce(gravityDirection * gravitationalForce, ForceMode.Acceleration);
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, -gravityDirection) * transform.rotation;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -gravityDirection, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject != gameObject)
            {
                float distanceToSurface = hit.distance - (transform.localScale.y * 0.5f);
                rb.position = transform.position + (gravityDirection * distanceToSurface);
            }
        }
    }



    void Update()
    {
        
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        Vector3 moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0f, verticalInput);
        Vector3 moveVelocity = moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(moveVelocity.x, rb.velocity.y, moveVelocity.z);
    }
}
```

I tried ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Bard, every A.I. language model that has the ability to understand code to fix this issue. None worked, and they just spat out basically the same code with reformatting (BingChat's reformatting actually made the code much simpler, so thanks ig).

Here is a link to the Unity project folder (Unity Editor Alpha 2023.2.0a15): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dfVD0PbYmKhhz14Xhim-LZQZ4FiaOsRx?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a force in Fixed Update and setting a velocity in the Update function for the same object. This two will interfere. Take the input from the player and compute the final force value taking in account the gravity and apply a single Add force to the object inside the fixed update.

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't work

Here's the code that I have right now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GNmeH4ewjkVnm1STr7BSPZXqfSi4lG5J/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found this answer from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khOLkjB4r7c)

Here's how to do it:

1. Attach these scripts into the main player mesh:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class playerRBController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 10.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float transferSpeed = 10.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForce = 10.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float maxJumpHeight = 10.0f;
    [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem landingParticles;
    [SerializeField, Range(0.0f, 1.0f)] private float landDistance = 0.4f;
    [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem takeOffParticles;

    private List<GameObject> worlds = new List<GameObject>();
    private int currentWorld = 0;
    private int prevWorld = 0;
    private Vector3 moveDirection;
    private Rigidbody playerRB;
    private Transform playerMesh;
    private FakeGravityBody worldGravity;

    private bool transferring = false;
    private bool landed = false;
    private float worldDistance = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        playerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        playerMesh = transform.GetChild(0).transform;
        worldGravity = GetComponent<FakeGravityBody>();

        worlds.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("World"));
        currentWorld = CurrentWorldIndex();

        speed = SpeedUpdate();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (transferring)
            return;

        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical")).normalized;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            WorldTransfer();

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
            Jump();

        RotateForward();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (transferring)
            return;

        playerRB.MovePosition(playerRB.position + transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime));
    }

    private void Jump()
    {
        float jumpHeight = Vector3.Distance(worlds[currentWorld].transform.position, transform.position) - maxJumpHeight;

        bool canJump = jumpHeight < maxJumpHeight;
        if (canJump)
        {
            Vector3 gravityDir = (worlds[currentWorld].transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            playerRB.AddForce(-gravityDir * jumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
            takeOffParticles.Play();
        }
    }

    private void WorldTransfer()
    {
        Jump();
        worldGravity.Attractor = null;

        bool isLastWorld = currentWorld + 1 >= worlds.Count;
        if (isLastWorld)
        {
            prevWorld = currentWorld;
            currentWorld = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            prevWorld = currentWorld;
            currentWorld++;
        }

        transferring = true;
        worldDistance = Vector3.Distance(worlds[prevWorld].transform.position, worlds[currentWorld].transform.position) - (worlds[prevWorld].GetComponent<FakeGravity>().WorldSize + worlds[currentWorld].GetComponent<FakeGravity>().WorldSize);
        StartCoroutine("ChangeWorlds");
    }

    private IEnumerator ChangeWorlds()
    {
        while (transferring)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine("TakeOff");
            yield return StartCoroutine("RotateToTarget");
            yield return StartCoroutine("TravelToTarget");
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator TakeOff()
    {
        bool done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            float jumpDistance = Vector3.Distance(worlds[prevWorld].transform.position, transform.position);

            bool isHighEnough = jumpDistance > (maxJumpHeight * 2.5);
            if (isHighEnough)
            {
                bool isMovingFast = playerRB.velocity.magnitude > 2f;
                if (isMovingFast)
                {
                    playerRB.velocity -= (transform.up * 10) * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else
                {
                    playerRB.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                    done = true;
                }
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator RotateToTarget()
    {
        bool done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            moveDirection = (worlds[currentWorld].transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, moveDirection), Time.deltaTime);

            bool isAligned = Vector3.Distance(moveDirection, transform.up) <= 0.01f;
            if (isAligned)
            {
                takeOffParticles.Play();
                done = true;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator TravelToTarget()
    {
        bool done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            moveDirection = (worlds[currentWorld].transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(worlds[currentWorld].transform.position, transform.position);

            bool isNearTarget = distance < (worldDistance * landDistance) + 5;
            if (isNearTarget)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.FromToRotation(-Vector3.up, moveDirection), Time.deltaTime);
                playerRB.MovePosition(playerRB.position + (moveDirection * (transferSpeed * 0.5f) * Time.deltaTime));
            }
            else
            {
                playerRB.MovePosition(playerRB.position + (moveDirection * transferSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
            }

            bool isCloseToTarget = distance < (worldDistance * landDistance);
            if (isCloseToTarget)
            {
                if (landed)
                {
                    worldGravity.Attractor = worlds[currentWorld].GetComponent<FakeGravity>();
                    ResetState();
                    done = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    landingParticles.Play();
                }
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private void RotateForward()
    {
        Vector3 dir = moveDirection;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.x, dir.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up);

        bool isMoving = Vector3.Magnitude(dir) > 0.0f;
        if (isMoving)
        {
            playerMesh.localRotation = targetRotation;
        }
    }

    private float SpeedUpdate()
    {
        float newSpeed = speed;

        bool isPlaneWorld = worldGravity.Attractor.gameObject.name == "PlaneWorld";
        if (isPlaneWorld)
        {
            newSpeed = speed / 2;
        }

        return newSpeed;
    }

    private int CurrentWorldIndex()
    {
        int worldIndex = 0;
        string worldName = worldGravity.Attractor.gameObject.name;
        int count = worlds.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            bool isCurrentWorld = worldName == worlds[i].name;
            if (isCurrentWorld)
            {
                worldIndex = i;
            }
        }

        return worldIndex;
    }

    private void ResetState()
    {
        transferring = false;
        landed = false;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (transferring)
        {
            bool isWorld = collision.transform.tag == "World";
            if (isWorld)
            {
                landed = true;
                landingParticles.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class FakeGravityBody : MonoBehaviour {

    // inspector variables
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Attractor object to be drawn to, if left blank first available world will be used")]
    private FakeGravity attractor;
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Set object solid once settled")]
    private bool setSolid = false;
    
    // privates
    private Transform _objTransform;
    private Rigidbody _objRigidbody;
    
    // properties
    public FakeGravity Attractor { get { return attractor; } set { attractor = value; } }
    
    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start () {
        // set rigidbody
        _objRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _objRigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        _objRigidbody.useGravity = false;
        _objTransform = transform;
        // get attractor if not provided
        if (attractor == null)
        {
            attractor = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("World").GetComponent<FakeGravity>();
        }
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update () {
        // return if kinematic
        if (_objRigidbody.isKinematic)
        {
            return;
        }
        // check if object sleeping yet
        if (setSolid)
        {
            ObjectResting();
        }
        // apply gravity to object
        if (attractor != null)
        {
            attractor.Attract(_objTransform);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if rigidbody is sleeping
    /// </summary>
    private void ObjectResting()
    {
        if(gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().IsSleeping())
        {
            _objRigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        }
    }
}
```

2. Now attach this script onto the gravity attractor (for my case, the moon):

```cs
/*********************************************************************************************************
 * The FakeGravity class should be place on your world object that other objects are to be drawn to.
 * *******************************************************************************************************/ 
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FakeGravity : MonoBehaviour {

    // inspector variables
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Amount of gravity to be applied to objects")]
    private float gravity = -10;
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Planet Radius")]
    private float size = 10;

    // privates
    private string _worldObjectTag = "World";
    private float _objRotSpeed = 50;
    private float _gravityBoost = 0;

    // properties
    public float WorldSize { get { return size; } }

    // Awake is called when the script instance is being loaded
    private void Awake()
    {
        gameObject.tag = _worldObjectTag;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates false gravity for world objects 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objBody"></param>
    public void Attract(Transform objBody)
    {
        // set planet gravity direction for the object body
        Vector3 gravityDir = (objBody.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Vector3 bodyUp = objBody.up;
        // apply gravity to objects rigidbody
        objBody.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(gravityDir * (gravity + _gravityBoost));
        // update the objects rotation in relation to the planet
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(bodyUp, gravityDir) * objBody.rotation;
        // smooth rotation
        objBody.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(objBody.rotation, targetRotation, _objRotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Function to increase world gravity during transfer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="increaseGravity"></param>
    public void IncreaseGravity(bool increaseGravity, float amount)
    {
        if(increaseGravity)
        {
            _gravityBoost = gravity * amount;
        }
        else
        {
            _gravityBoost = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Add this code to the camera:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // inspector variables
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Player transform for camera to follow")]
    private Transform playerTransform;
    [SerializeField, Tooltip("Camera offset from player (x not used)")]
    private Vector3 offsetPosition = new Vector3(0, 5, 5);
    [SerializeField]
    private bool lookAt = true;

    // privates
    private Transform _mainCam = null;

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start()
    {
        if(playerTransform == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("CameraMovement is missing playerTransform");
        }
        else
        {
            _mainCam = Camera.main.transform;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        UpdateCamera();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update camera position and rotation
    /// </summary>
    private void UpdateCamera()
    {
        if (playerTransform == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        // camera rig position
        transform.position = playerTransform.position + -(playerTransform.forward * offsetPosition.z) + (playerTransform.up * offsetPosition.y);
        // point camera at player
        if (lookAt)
        {
            // point camera at player using players up direction
            _mainCam.LookAt(playerTransform, playerTransform.up);
        }
        else
        {
            _mainCam.LookAt(playerTransform);
        }
    }
}
```